# Differences between def up and def change in migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, migration

What's the difference between `def up; end` and `def change; end` ?
I've got code

```
class CreateTweets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tweets do |t|
      t.string :status
      t.integer :zombie_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

what does it change if I define `def up` instead of `def change` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `up` method should be accompanied by a `down` method that can be used to undo the migration's changes. For example, if you wrote the example in your question using up and down you would need the following code:

```
class CreateTweets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :tweets do |t|
      t.string :status
      t.integer :zombie_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :tweets
  end
end
```

The `change` method, on the other hand, can be reversed automatically by Rails so there's no need to manually create a `down` method.

`change` was introduce to replace `up` and `down` because most `down` methods could easily be predicted based on the `up` method (in the example above `drop_table` is clearly the reverse of `create_table`).

In situations where the reverse operation can't be automatically derived, you can either use the `up` and `down` methods, or call the [`reversible`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html#method-i-reversible) method from your `change` method.

See the [sections 3.6 - 3.7 of the Rails migration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-the-change-method) for more information.